# Can we deploy jhipster applications to on-premises or self-hosted server?

Tags: jhipster

In the [jhipster homepage](https://www.jhipster.tech/) , I could not find how to deploy to a on-premises or self-hosted server.

So I googled with keywords "jhipster deploy on-premises" or "jhipster deploy self-hosted", but I could not find the associated information.

Can we deploy jhipster applications to on-premises or self-hosted server?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a standard spring boot app, so everywhere you can deploy e.g. an executable jar file jhipster can be deployed. Maybe you can have a look at boot's official documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html

Comment: @atomfrede Thank you so much for your answer. I'm glad to be solved my question.